# Converting collections.Dictionary to JSON data in typescript

Tags: javascript, json, typescript

I have a collection dictionary like:

`val arrayCollection = collections.Dictionary<string, any>();`

with values like:

```
{"a", "abc"},
{"b", 123},
{"c", something else}
```

How can I convert this collection dictionary to a JSON?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well, have you tried `JSON.stringify(arrayCollection)`?

Answer (score 0):

JSON stands for JavaScript object notation. Your dictionary object is already a JSON. Just do with it whatever you need. The Dictionary type doesn't really exist at run time, and methods are part of the prototype so they won't be sent to the server or stored in the local storage.

This is the value of your dictionary object at run time:

```
[{"a", "abc"},
{"b", 123},
{"c", something else}]
```

As you can see: This is JSON!

Comment: Hi, thank you for  the reply.. but if I add something else to the collection like an image how can I convert it to JSON?

Comment: @AngularDoubts whatever way you're storing your image. You can store it as a string containing the path, or as a byte array, it's still JSON.